# How to provide access dynamically to different profiles for a single web page in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, metadata-api

For a sample VF page, if depending upon certain logic we want to change visibility of a page for profiles dynamically, how can we do that ?
Example - Profile1, Profile2 ....Profile5 have access to VF1.
But later on this should change dynamically from Profile1 to 4 thus excluding 5.

Can we modify metadata api in SFDC to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Visualforce page can inspect the current user context using the [`$Profile`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_profile.htm), [`$Permission`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_permission.htm) (for custom permissions), and [`$User`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm) global merge fields.

You can then conditionally render page elements and content, or dynamically determine whether or not to provide access to specific pieces of functionality.

A solution built around that type of introspection will be more flexible and sustainable, and provide a better user experience, than attempting to use the Metadata API to dynamically change permissions.